# Adding radiobutton within radiobutton like parent-child sub menu andfood

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Multiple and parent-subchild radio buttons.
eg

```
○Radiobutton1  

         ○Subradiobutton1-1

         ○Subradiobutton1-2  

○Radiobutton2    
         ○Subradiobutton2-1  
        ○Subradiobutton2-2
```

How can i implement in java activity android

What i want is to execute actions based on radiobutton:
For eg.
If i select Radiobutton1 it will execute all actions specified under Subradiobutton1-1 & Subradiobutton1-2; OR; If i select Subradiobutton1-2 it will execute only action specified under that button.

I know how to add radio.group but i want to add sub radio button within radio button

Comment: this question be a bit more explained!

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are used for selecting one option from a set. So you can put sub checkboxes instead of subradiobuttons and have an array of ids of those checkboxes for all the radio buttons. Then you can define an onClick method for radio buttons which will select all checkboxes under the selected radio button.

```java
int checkBoxIds[][];
//callback for when a radio button is selected/disselcted
public void onSelectionChange(int radioButtonNo, boolean allSelected){
    for(int checkBoxId: checkBoxIds[radioButtonNo]){
        if(allSelected){
            findViewById<CheckBox>(checkBoxIds[radioButtonNo]).setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            findViewById<CheckBox>(checkBoxIds[radioButtonNo]).setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
//onClick method for radio buttons
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_button0:
            onSelectionChange(0, checked);
            break;
        case R.id.radio_button1:
            onSelectionChange(1, checked);
            break;
        case R.id.radio_button2:
            onSelectionChange(2, checked);
            break;
    }
}
```